# Visual needs addressible cursor or upline capability

Tags: vim, zsh

i switched from grml zshrc to this zsh config (http://dotshare.it/dots/100/) because it seems more handable to me than grml's config.

after switching i have the problem that i can't start vim:

```
benedikt@laptop:pts/2: ~
» vim
Visual needs addressible cursor or upline capabilit
```

anybody now what this could be?

```
TERM = rxvt-unicode-256color
```

Comment: try to set the TERM with `rxvt-256color`

Comment: same as with rxvt-unicode-256color

Comment: Do you have all the terminfo's installed for you computer? (Look for a file named rxvt-unicode-256color in /usr/share/terminfo and its subdirectories)

Comment: Did you try without "your" zsh config? And, just to be sure, are you actually using urxvt?

Answer (score 0):

```
export TERM=
```

and if does not work, export TERMCAP (A string describing your terminal capabilities used by BSD) from orginal vi readme:

```
TERMCAP="vt102|$TERM|dec vt102:"'\
    :do=^J:co#80:li#24:cl=50\E[;H\E[2J:\
    :le=^H:bs:cm=5\E[%i%d;%dH:nd=2\E[C:up=2\E[A:\
    :ce=3\E[K:cd=50\E[J:so=2\E[7m:se=2\E[m:us=2\E[4m:ue=2\E[m:\
    :md=2\E[1m:mr=2\E[7m:mb=2\E[5m:me=2\E[m:is=\E[1;24r\E[24;1H:\
    :rs=\E>\E[?3l\E[?4l\E[?5l\E[?7h\E[?8h:ks=\E[?1h\E=:ke=\E[?1l\E>:\
    :ku=\EOA:kd=\EOB:kr=\EOC:kl=\EOD:kb=^H:\
    :ho=\E[H:k1=\EOP:k2=\EOQ:k3=\EOR:k4=\EOS:pt:sr=5\EM:vt#3:\
    :sc=\E7:rc=\E8:cs=\E[%i%d;%dr:vs=\E[?7l:ve=\E[?7h:\
    :mi:al=\E[L:dc=\E[P:dl=\E[M:ei=\E[4l:im=\E[4h:'
export TERMCAP
```

Answer (score 0):

To whomever stumbles upon this thread when trying to install "oldschool" vanilla `vi` on linux (ubuntu in my case), which might give you the EXACT same error message:

First of all, you are surely procrastinating at this point. Don't you have more pressing things to do? (looking at myself there, mostly...)

But I found this thread on [a linux forum](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=130599) that helped me figure it out:
in the `Makefile` I had to uncomment the line that said

```
TERMLIB = ncurses
```

and comment out the one (close by) where it said `TERMLIB = termlib`. Then rebuild `vi` and you should no longer see the error message described in this (six years old!) question.

Comment: Instead of editing ex-vi's makefile, you could compile it by running `make TERMLIB=ncurses` and install it by running `sudo make INSTALL=install install`.